# Custom waf task does neither run nor find sources

Tags: waf

In my `wscript` I run some custom Task (`dummy`) after the `apply_link` method, and this works fine.

After this `dummy`-task has finished I want to collect all of my output files (let it be `*.dll`, `*.exe`, `*.o`, `*.a` or `*.elf`) and run another task on these output file, but I get two errors:

- The task seems not to be generated at all.
- The output files found by `bld.path.get_bld().ant_glob(...)` are not passed to the task.

The`wscript` looks like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

top = '.'
out = 'build'

VERSION = '0.0.0'
APPNAME = 'app'

from waflib import Task, TaskGen

def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_c')

def configure(conf):
    conf.load('compiler_c')

def build(bld):
    bld.program(target='app', features='dummy', source='main.c')
    bld.path.get_bld().ant_glob('**/*.elf **/*.a **/*.o', quiet=True)
    bld(bld.path.get_bld().ant_glob('**/*.elf **/*.a **/*.o', quiet=True))


class tsk_1(Task.Task):
    run_str = 'echo Hello from dummy and ${SRC} > ${TGT}'
    color = 'GREEN'


@TaskGen.feature('dummy')
@TaskGen.after_method('apply_link')
def add_dummy_task(self):
    # create one more *.o file
    self.dummy_task = self.create_task(
        'tsk_1',
        src=self.link_task.outputs[0],
        tgt=self.link_task.outputs[0].change_ext('hello.o'))

@TaskGen.extension('.elf')
@TaskGen.extension('.a')
@TaskGen.extension('.o')
@TaskGen.after('add_dummy_task')
def process(self, node):
    self.sk = self.create_task('size', node)

class size(Task.Task):
    color = 'PINK'
    def run(self):
        print('Another hello from ${self.inputs[0]}')
```

Shell output:

```
$ python waf clean configure build -v
'clean' finished successfully (0.036s)
Setting top to                           : /cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/waf-tests/test1
Setting out to                           : /cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/waf-tests/test1/build
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : 09:11:43 runner ['/usr/bin/gcc', '-dM', '-E', '-']
/usr/bin/gcc
'configure' finished successfully (0.123s)
Waf: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/waf-tests/test1/build'
[1/3] Compiling main.c
09:11:43 runner ['/usr/bin/gcc', '../main.c', '-c', '-o/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/waf-tests/test1/build/main.c.1.o']
[2/3] Linking build/app.exe
09:11:43 runner ['/usr/bin/gcc', '-Wl,--enable-auto-import', 'main.c.1.o', '-o/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/waf-tests/test1/build/app.exe', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Wl,-Bdynamic']
[3/3] Compiling build/app.exe
09:11:43 runner ' echo Hello from dummy and app.exe > apphello.o '
Waf: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/waf-tests/test1/build'
'build' finished successfully (0.356s)
```

If I re-run the `build` command `waf` at least finds the the output files (of course, now they are alredy present ;) ), but not even then it runs my other custom task:

```
$ python waf build
Waf: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/waf-tests/test1/build'
[/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/waf-tests/test1/build/apphello.o, /cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/waf-tests/test1/build/main.c.1.o]
Waf: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/waf-tests/test1/build'
'build' finished successfully (0.040s)
```

So my questions summarize to:

- Why does `waf` not respect the constraint to search for the output files after `@TaskGen.after('add_dummy_task')` has finished
- Why does the task not run, even if the files are present since a previous build is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constraint added by `Taskgen.after` is only on the order of task generator methods. It does not imply ANY constraint on tasks. You can see that by using the `--zone task_gen` option.

The only source you described is `main.c` which does not trigger your `process` method.

Probably a typo, but your second task generator has no `source` attribute needed by `Taskgen.extension`, nor `features` attribute. Try:

```py
bld(
    source = bld.path.get_bld().ant_glob('**/*.elf **/*.a **/*.o'),
    features = 'dummy',
    quiet = True
)
```