# Create waf size feature

Tags: waf

I have created a waf feature to run `size` on all build files, but I do not want to do it like I orginally wanted (see [Custom waf task does neither run nor find sources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53665743/8972161)).

So I wrote now a feature, which works generally, but does again not find the sources correctly. I use `@after('apply_link')`, therefore the binaries should be present...

- First run: all binaries are generated, but `size` has no input files.
- Second run: all binaries are there and the `size` feature is run correctly. Why is it like this?

waf feature:

```py
from waflib.TaskGen import extension
from waflib.TaskGen import after

class size(Task.Task):
    color = 'BLUE'
    run_str = '${SIZE} ${SRC} > ${TGT}'

@extension('.o', '.a', '.elf')
@after('apply_link')
def add_size(self, node):
    name = 'size'
    out = node.change_ext('.log')
    task = self.create_task(name, node, out)
    try:
        self.size_tasks.append(task)
    except AttributeError:
        self.size_tasks = [task]
    return task
```

Using the feature:

```
    bld(source=bld.path.get_bld().ant_glob('**/*.o **/*.a **/*.elf'),
    features='size')
```

Side question: Is there a better option to log the output of this task as redirecting the output with `>` into the output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `Taskgen.after` decorator you just tell waf to run the `add_size` method after the `apply_link` method in the task generation step. As your task generator does not link anything, you do not have any `apply_link` method, you don't need it.

Your problem is that you use `ant_glob` on the build directory. The first time, there is nothing in it, so `ant_glob` returns nothing, so your task have nothing to do :)

You have to add a feature to the task generator that creates the objects you want to size. For example:

```py
@feature("size") # or feature("*") for every taskgen
@after('apply_link')
def process_sizes(self):

    if getattr(self, "link_task", None) is None:
        return

    objets_to_size = []

    objects_to_size.extend(self.link_task.inputs) # object files
    objects_to_size.extend(self.link_task.outputs) # exe, libs ...

    for node in objects_to_size:
         out = node.change_ext('.log')
         self.create_task("size", node, out)
```

To use:

```py
bld.program(source = "main.c", features = "size", target = "myexe")
```

You will get the size of all files of the link process.

`@Taskgen.extension` is only used by `Taskgen.process_source` which process the `source` attribute of the task generator. It does not work well with intermediate objects not expressed in wscript.

Comment: Hm, this does not work on my machine ``Cycle detected in the method execution:
- process_use after ['propagate_uselib_vars']
- process_source after ['process_use', 'apply_link']
- apply_link after ['process_use', 'update_sources']
- propagate_uselib_vars after []
- update_sources after ['process_source']
``

Comment: @waf3: yep, my mistake. `apply_link` comes after `process_source`. I will edit my answer ...

Comment: ok, wonderfull, it works now :) thanks for the edit! But I can not figure out, what tasks are generating the *.a and *.elf files, since there only seems to be the `link_task` described in to the documenation.

Comment: static libs are usually generated by the `bld.stlib` shortcut. You can use `link_task.outputs`. For .elf I do not know. Probably some side effect of compilation/link ?

Comment: If you have a clear mapping between .o and .elf for example, you can use change_ext to achieve what you want

Comment: Your hint to use the `link_task.outputs` also, was the solution. It is now working for all binary output! Perfect answer, many thanks again!

Comment: is there a option to "reduce" the logging level of the feature?

Comment: You can use `Logs.debug("myfeature: any log message")`. Those logs will not print on terminal, unless you use the option `--zone myfeature`. Use `Logs.info("any log")` for logs you always want to print.